# Are birds a theme of Enrique Villasis's poetry, and why?

Tags: poetry, motif, enrique-villasis, filipino-language

Enrique Villasis is a Filipino poet, and every poem of his that I've found is something to do with birds:

- [Birds in Flight, 1965](https://www.wordswithoutborders.org/article/september-2020-poetry-contest-birds-in-flight-1965-enrique-villasis-bernard)
- [Birds of Paradise, 1965](https://www.wordswithoutborders.org/article/november-2019-philippines-birds-of-paradise-1965-enrique-villasis)
- [Birdman, 1973, and White Bird Dark Shadow, 1962](https://exchanges.uiowa.edu/issues/iterations/two-poems-by-enrique-villasis/)

(all links are to webpages including English translations of these poems originally in Filipino)

Are birds a significant theme in the poetry of Enrique Villasis? If so, then why? Do they have some personal significance to him, or does he find them a natural "medium" for channelling ideas and emotions, or what?

Comment: He also writes about [crocodiles](https://lunchticket.org/buwaya-crocodile/).